# Detecting useragent works for android but not iphone?

Tags: javascript, typescript, user-agent

**Goal**: Detect if user is on iPhone/iPad/Android (mobile device) and run some code based on that condition

**Problem/What happens**: It seems to detect android, but doesn't detect iPhone/iPod.

**What I've tried:**
I am testing this with Chrome devtools. I select user agent from Chrome Devtools to something like: Chrome - iPhone , or Chrome - Android Mobile.

[image: user agent iPhone]

I've tried debugging this, and I get:
uagent = "mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 9_1 like mac os x) applewebkit/601.1.46 (khtml, like gecko) version/9.0 mobile/13b137 safari/601.1"

Yet it completely skips the condition

I've also looked at different articles and my match condition looks like it is correct. In fact I got this one from a SO article. But it looks the same on W3Schools, mozilla documentation, etc.
I also tried moving the code back out of the service method and into the component itself but that did not help. I remember testing this and it working at a certain point(with iPhone as useragent)  but not sure what has changed.

**Angular/TypeScript:**

```
this.isMobile = this.securityService.isUserAgentMobile();

isUserAgentMobile(): boolean {
        var isMobile = false;
        var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (uagent.match(/iPad|iPhone|android/)) {
            console.log("user agent is mobile!");
            isMobile = true;
        }
        return isMobile;
}
```

Comment: Which model of iPhone are you using and what's the browser and it's version if you can please share

Comment: @ZainZafar . I am choosing it from Chrome's DevTools (F12) under network conditions. It literally says "Chrome - iPhone" . I will attach a screenshot

Comment: A lowercase string never matches words containing uppercase letters.

Comment: @str Name checks out :). And *facepalm* , that was it! So obvious, don't know how I missed that. Thank you. Feel free to put as answer and ill select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its set to lowercase, the match has to be lowercase as well:

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (uagent.match(/ipad|iphone|android/))
```